# Singular matrix when implementing GMM from scratch

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, mixed-models

[image][image]

In the EM algorithm for Gaussian Mixture Models. We go through the above steps. 9.23 composes the E step and 9.24,9.25,9.26 composes the M step.

However, Implementing 9.25 always gave $\Sigma_K$ that were singular. No matter mean or sigma I chose, the algorithm would create a singular $\Sigma$ after the first iteration.

My implementation of M step:

```
for k in range(K):
    mu[:,k] = np.sum(X*gamma[:,k][:,None],axis = 0)/N[k]

for k in range(K):
    A = X - mu[:,k]
    SigmaK = A.T@(A *gamma[:,k][:,None])
    SigmaK /=self.N[k]
    sigma[k] = SigmaK  

pi = N*(1/N.sum())
```

Is there something particularly wrong with this implementation that would cause covariance to always be singular?

Comment: Have you tried debugging the equation all by itself on a trivial toy data such as [[0,1],[1,0]] and compare that to manual results.

Comment: very good idea.